# How to get comma separated JSON data on its on line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I am retrieving data from an API that looks like this -

```
"title": "Company Name",
"markets": "US, Asia",
"market_ids": "4, 5"
```

I need to add this data to a dropdown menu like this -

```
<option value="4">US</option>
```

So I need to remove the commas and any duplicates (there will be many entries with the same market)

I was thinking something like this at first -

```
      $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:9001/api/directory',
        }).done(function (data, status, xhr) {
            let markets = [];
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                markets.push(value.markets);
        })
        markets = [...new Set(markets.toString().split(','))];

        for (market of markets) {
                $(".directory-input.market").append(
                    `<option value="" class="market-option">${market}</option>`)
            };
    });
```

This works to separate the market names by comma and get rid of any duplicates, but the problem is that I can't add the market ID to the value. I need the market ID to be accessible as well.

Comment: is the number of id and market the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have control of the API design, something like

```js
{
  title: 'Company Name',
  markets: [
    { id: 4, name: 'Asia' },
    { id: 4, name: 'US' }
  ]
}
```

would make usage easier and more clear.

Given the example though, and making a couple assumptions:

1. market names are unique
2. market_ids is ordered same as markets including duplication

this should work

```js
$
  .ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:9001/api/directory',
  })
  .done((data, status, xhr) => {
    const marketSelect = $(".directory-input.market");
    const labels = Array.from(new Set(data.markets.split(', ')));
    const ids = Array.from(new Set(data.market_ids.split(', ')));
    
    labels.forEach(
        (label, idx) => 
            marketSelect.append(`<option value="${ids[idx]}" class="market-option">${label}</option>`)
    );
  });
```

Comment: To add a finer point on @dhusons suggestion to change the response API. This code (or any reasonable code) will fail if you have markets that have commas in the name.

Comment: This will break as well if there is an extra space before or after one of the market names.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there will be the same number of ids and markets. Note, if you are adding a a lot of options, you probaly will want to create the select itself with options as a documentFragment to avoid repaints.

```js
const data = { 
"title": "Company Name",
"markets": "US, Asia, Asia",
"market_ids": "4, 5, 5"
};

const marketSelectEl = document.getElementById('market-select');
const markets = Array.from(
  new Set(data.markets.split(',').map(m => m.trim()))
  );
const market_ids =  Array.from(
  new Set(data.markets.split(',').map(m => m.trim()))
  );
const marketOptions = markets
  .map((marketName, index) => {
    const optionEl = document.createElement('option');
    optionEl.value = market_ids[index];
    optionEl.innerText = marketName;
    return optionEl;
  })
  
  ;

marketOptions.forEach(el => marketSelectEl.append(el));
```

```html
<select id="market-select" style="width: 200px;">
</select>
```